# SCNAction not firing

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit

My `SCNAction` does not work, even though the compiler gets there. This is my code to create the `SCNAction`:

```
println("log 1") //to check the program gets there
let moveInit1: SCNAction = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(0, -3, 0), duration: 1)
moveInit1.timingMode = SCNActionTimingMode.EaseOut
cube.runAction(moveInit1)
println("log 2") //check again
```

The output is `log 1` as well as `log 2` but there is no animation happening...

Does anyone have an idea why?

**Note**

I have this exact same code in another method, there it does work.

Comment: if you use `let` vs. `var` for your action, are you sure you can override the timingMode? I don't think `let` properties are supposed to be changed.

Comment: Yes it does work, does not give me any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. When I created my node globally (so it is available for multiple methods) I set it to `let`. I redefined the node with `var` inside my `setup()` method, Xcode did not complain, obviously I had two different nodes with the same name.
The first node (the constant one) did not contain all the configurations I made in `setup()`.

This is what caused the issues, it now runs perfectly :)

Answer (score 4):

I have no clue why your code isn't working, but this code works for me.

```
var node = SCNNode.new()
node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
var action = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(0, 3, 0), duration: 1)
action.timingMode = SCNActionTimingMode.EaseOut
node.runAction(action)
```

Comment: I have a slight idea why it does not work. I have created the node outside of the VCs to make it available to multiple methods. Then, in `setup()` I configure the node and it's properties. Is it possible, since this code is in another method (and in an `if`-block) it does not work because of that?

Comment: I found the problem, see my answer below. Thank you though for your help :)